# loop does not read all the subset that assigned

Tags: r

I am trying to make a loop that the genes in the datTab from the subset "Gene" but the "i" only contains ‘h‘ from the Gene list when runs the code.
It repeatedly shows ‘h‘ only.  I‘d like to know how to make the "i" can include all Gene list.

```
Gene <- c("a","c","d","h")
rankData <- list()

for (i in Gene) {
datTab <- read.csv2(file = sprintf("Test.csv",i),
                   row.names=1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header= TRUE)
geneNames <- rownames(datTab)
datTab <- apply(datTab,2,as.numeric)
rownames(datTab) <- geneNames
rankData[[i]] <- data.frame(datTab)
}
```

Comment: One issue is that `read.csv2(file = sprintf("Test.csv",i)` should probably be `read.csv2(file = sprintf("%s.csv",i)`.

Comment: You need to define the variable rankData outside the loop and then add the new data to it..  Otherwise it is overwritten on each iteration.